# Installing XAP file says it is unsupported

Tags: apps

I am currently trying to install 6snap using the XAP file. The option for Install Local Apps works fine and the XAP file is in the right place on the SD card but when I try to install it, it says it's not supported. [image: Error showing app not supported.]

I am guessing that's because it verifies the app before installing it, and it needs to still be available in the store, but is there any other way to install it?

Comment: Have you used this app on this device before?

Comment: No, this is the first time I have tried to install it. (and as it's not longer available on the store I tried to use the XAP file instead.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[6snap has been pulled from the store](http://www.windowscentral.com/unsurprisingly-6snap-wont-be-coming-back-windows-phone-store) a while ago as Snapchat does not allow other apps to connect to their service. You can only install apps from your SD card if the app is still available in the store.

And even if you could install it, I'd imagine Snapchat has already blocked 6snap's access to the service.

Comment: Yeah, I had a feeling that was the case... thanks anyway though!

Answer (score -1):

Use [specter](https://www.microsoft.com/de-de/store/apps/app/9nblggh5kldb?tduid=(c31b6fa87aaebc7568d2d76e9744ff4b)(213688)(2775093)()()), its another snapchat client. I guess Snapchat banned 6snap, but Specter is amazing. It even got an update yesterday.